# Mailgun email stuck in "Accepted" state

Tags: mailgun

When I use Mailgun to send emails via API, everything goes well when the recipient is a Gmail address.

[image: Mailgun works with Gmail]

But when the recipient's address is my domain's address (contact@mydomain.fr), the mail is stuck in "Accepted" state and never goes to "Delivered" state nor "Failed" state. Here are 2 mails:

[image: Mailgun doesn't work with custom domain]

All DNS are well configured and I use a free Mailgun plan.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 possible common cases where this can happen:

1. If the customer you are sending to does not have MX records set up. When a message is "Accepted" into the system, it will attempt to look up the MX record for the recipient domain to know where to send the "Accepted" message. If the MX record does not exist, it can cause the message to get stuck in an "Accepted" state.
2. Another instance is if you are sending to your own domain registered with Mailgun (inbound message), with the Mailgun MX records set up. Keep in mind that Mailgun does not have inboxes. In order to ensure the mail goes somewhere, "Routes" must be in place to forward and "deliver" the mail to a destination. If you do not have "Routes" setup, the message will be stuck in an accepted state, as it does not know where to be sent to.